# Repeating subject for emphasis okay?

Tags: grammar

For example I find myself saying things like:

> What did you win, bro?

I could leave out the "bro" and the sentence would be complete but I unconsciously add emphasis with the subject again because it's the way I speak.

In a conversation, would it be okay to do the same in Japanese for emphasis as well? Something like:

> 何を当てるの[兄貴]{あにき}?

I'm unsure since in Japanese you can omit the subject altogether.  Or maybe it just doesn't sound or translate the same, thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by *win*? "Win (a prize / a million yen in a lottery / etc)" is not 勝つ but 当てる in Japanese.

Comment: "bro" is in this context a vocative. Are you asking if you can use vocatives when asking Japanese questions?

Comment: @virmaior Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As virmaior said in the comments, "bro" in this sentence is a vocative - it's used to address "bro". It's not the subject of the sentence. The subject of the English sentence is "you".

Vocatives' natural position is at the end or beginning of a sentence. In writing, you usually put a comma to separate it. When speaking, you make a short pause.

Thus

> What did you win, bro?

to me looks better written as

> 何が当たったの、兄貴?

(Note, I changed the structure of the sentence based on 非回答者's comment below.)

As for omitting or adding a vocative, yes, you can use it or not, not very dissimilar to English:

> 何が当たったの、兄貴? What did you win, bro?
>
> 兄貴、何が当たったの? Bro, what did you win?
>
> 何が当たったの? What did you win?

Comment: I'm not sure if 兄貴 is the best word for "bro". Please correct if it's wrong.

Comment: Err yea, I have to agree with Szymon. I've literally never heard anyone speak like this. I think that よ might be what you're looking for - 何を当てたのよ  (but tbh, in speaking I think just leaving it at の is normal)

Comment: 「何が当たったの？」 would sound so much more natural.  「何を当てたの？」 is just a "direct" translation.  http://www.cedyna.co.jp/camp/751/images/img_main.jpg

Comment: @非回答者 Thank you for the comment, I updated my post.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, so take this with a grain of salt, but how would something like お前 sound in place of 兄貴? お前 is likely rougher than "bro", but I've never heard anyone address a male friend as 兄貴.

Comment: @Monburan Completely different meaning, really. Makes it sound accusatory.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to ask about it as a side note. The question is not about the pronoun choice.

Comment: @Darius Thank you for the clarification. I was under the impression お前 could also be used in a more friendly manner among close friends.
Also, apologies for the digression. The subject of what pronouns might sound natural is best saved for another question.

Comment: @Monburan It can be used in a friendly manner among closer friends, but when it's at the end of the sentence like that, it has the same flavor as "なんだよ、お前" or "何をしたんだよ、お前", which can of course still be said among friends but it's sort of a playful accusation in that case (IMO -- not a native speaker either :-).

Comment: @snailboat Well, the OP did provide "bro", so while we could choose to ignore that, it's not like they didn't provide necessary context, I think. (It is at least pretty apparent to me the intended usage of "bro" there.)